# EclipseLink ManyToMany relation - List is empty

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I have following configuration:

Class Course:

```
@Entity
public class Course implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_COURSE",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ID_COURSE")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ID_STUDENT")})
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Class Student:

```
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
```

Im using Spring-data, and the problem is that when I want to get my Student object, courses list is always empty (even with FetchType.EAGER):

```
studentRepository.findByFirstName("Name").get(0).getCourses().size() == 0
```

Above configuration works perfectly with usage of hibernate. Does anyone know what is a problem here ? Does EclipseLink needs something more ? Additionally I verified data with pgAdmin and data is saved as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EclipseLink uses a shared cache enabled by default, so if you didn't populate the Student's courses list when you were persisting them, they will remain that way in the cache until they get reloaded.  Set both sides of your bidirectional relationship (always recommended, as JPA does NOT set them for you).

You can can force queries to refresh using a query hint, or disable the shared cache if needed.  See 
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F

Comment: Thank you, setting <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/> worked for me. But I dont really underestand what you mean by:

Comment: "Set both sides of your bidirectional relationship (always recommended, as JPA does NOT set them for you)." - can you please give more details, or example ?